# Why does only the first of my modals load as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a little problem.
I have six modal images but only one of them is loading right.
Where is my mistake? How do I have to change my code?

I've tried to use a for loop but it doesn't happen again.

I'm using `document.getElementsByClassName('myImages')` but it doesn't happen again.

Here is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/r.jpg" class="myImages" id="myImg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/q.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Тениска Playboy</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/w.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/e.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>

</div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/1.jpeg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/2.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Тениска Playboy</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/3.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <img src="pictures/e.jpg" id="myImg" class="myImages" style="height:100%;max-height:300px;width:100%;max-width:300px">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Mъжка тениска</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="Socials">
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you have duplicate IDs (which is invalid markup). Use class names instead.

Comment: In which line i have to do this?

Comment: The HTML; you have duplicate `myModal`, `img01` and `caption`, all of which are invalid. You're already using `getElementsByClassName` and even `this` in your function, though the JavaScript will need a slight tweak too :)

Comment: Do I have to remove "id" from "img src tag"? I can't understand you.. please explain in more detail..

Comment: You cannot have `id="myModal"` one one element, and `id="myModal"` on another. ID values _must_ be unique. JavaScript will only act on the first element with a particular ID value.

Comment: @j08691 yes I'm using bootstrap;

Comment: @isherwood ok but where I have to put this selection : <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                    <div id="caption"></div>
                </div>

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me.